# Prestashop : use Product class in personnal script

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I need to create a cron script to process products (add, delete, update) when I get them from a raw data file from a third party firm which sends a new file (data separated with ;) whenever a product is changed (added, deleted, updated).

I tried using the Product class (from Product.php) to add new products in the shop. The problem at first was that I got this error :

> class 'ObjectModel' not found in importProducts.php

I found an apparent solution, which was to require_once the config and init file from the config folder in importProduct.php :

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../init.php');
```

The require points to the right files. My file is located in a new folder, called "crontasks".

prestashop/crontaskt/import.php
(import.php starts importProduct.php)

But now there is a new error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
>
> ```
> SELECT c.id_category 
> FROM ps_category_product cp 
> LEFT JOIN ps_category c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category) 
> INNER JOIN ps_category_shop category_shop ON (category_shop.id_category = c.id_category AND category_shop.id_shop = 1) 
> WHERE cp.id_category NOT IN (18) 
> AND cp.id_product =
> ```
>
> thrown in D:\Travail\BUSCI\prestashop\prestashop\classes\db\Db.php on line 791

(they don't appear, but around the query are < br />< br />< pre >...< /pre > without the spaces in it)
Problem is, I checked in the database, and the columns are all there, and I don't get why there is a problem on that line.
Also, I could not find from which file that query was. I looked in Product.php, and I found one very similar but not exactly the same :

```
    $result = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
        SELECT c.`id_category`
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category` c ON (c.`id_category` = cp.`id_category`)
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('category', 'c', true, null, true).'
        WHERE cp.`id_category` NOT IN ('.implode(',', array_map('intval', $categories)).')
        AND cp.id_product = '.$this->id
    );
```

line 1051 in Product.php, method updateCategories.

I could not find anything similar in Category.php or any other file I looked in. But this query is missing the inner join, so I don't know if that's really the one. I suppose the problem comes from the fact that there is nothing after the =, but I don't know if that's just a character limitation (amount of characters printed in an error) or if it is the error. I'm feeling a little lost.

I did not change any files from prestashop. This is the latest update I just installed a week ago on my computer. The tests are done in local, on my computer.

I would really appreciate some help.

Excuse me for my english, it's not amazing.

**Edit :**

So I searched through the whole project, in every file for the line

```
INNER JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_shop
```

and could not find it. I tried taking away the extra spaces, just in case, but could not find the file in which this sql query is in.

Comment: Yes the last line is the problem with no value after =. What is your code for this SQL execution?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know where the code is from, nor what it does. I've looked in the files and can't find it. I found something similar, but the error does not tell me where it found that query in the first place, which does not help.
It's not from my files (in fact, I planned on writing no query at all in my cron script, just use those from Product.php).
Well at least now I know the error is the second half of that = statement. Thank you.

Comment: Set `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);` in prestashop `config/defines.inc.php` and it should show prestashop db error exception which will also display the stack of methods which executed the query so you can trace where the problem is.

Comment: On a Product import, simply ditch the category reindexation part, it takes forever and is frankly quite useless. You can always rebuild id afterwards with blocklayered

Comment: I already did, the error I posted is exactly what I get. Nothing more than that.
Is there an other define I need to change to show the stack of methods ? Julien, how do I do that ?

Comment: I used phpStorm research through the whole project to find that precise INNER JOIN line (along with _DB_PREFIX_ and all), and I could not find it. I have no idea where it comes from nor how I should repair it since it does not appear to be in the files.

Comment: `Shop::addSqlAssociation('category', 'c', true, null, true)` is building the `category_shop` INNER JOIN

Comment: Thank you a lot. Now I see what you meant by "category reindexation", I was trying to use the query from up there **before** giving the product an ID, which was not very smart.
Can I mark your answer as the solution ?